# ¿Como puedo mover todos los archivos que encuentro usando el comando find en unix?

Tags: bash, terminal, unix

Hola queria mover todos los archivos .txt a un directorio en especifico pero estos archivos se encuentran en **múltiples carpetas** por eso me preguntaba si existía un parámetro del comando find para mover todos los archivos que encuentra a un determinado directorio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existen varias formas alternativas. Teniendo en cuenta que etiquetas Bash, voy a proponer dos ejemplos concretos, iniciando con crear directorios de prueba (usando la expansión de bash):

```sh
mkdir dir{A,B}
touch dirA/archivo{1,2,3,4}
```

Esto crea dos directorios, `dirA` y `dirB`. En `dirA`, crea cuatro archivos que comparten prefijo `archivo` y finalizan en 1, 2, 3 y 4.

## Método 1: `xargs -0` (recomendado en GNU/Linux)

Aprovechar que en GNU se puede usar find | xargs con argumentos terminados en NULL, y usarlos con mv, con la opción que permite especificar el directorio de destino (target) y listar los orígenes AL FINAL.

```sh
find dirA -name "archivo*" -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t dirB
```

**Ventaja de usar xargs**: es que la línea de comandos para mv se construye hasta el límite definido por el sistema ANTES de ejecutarse, por lo tanto las llamadas al comando SON POCAS, y cada una trabaja con múltiples archivos.

**Ventaja de usar cadenas terminadas en NULL (`-print0` y `-0`)**: No importa que los nombres de archivo contengan espacios, tabs o carácteres extravagantes. Cada nombre de archivo es una cadena terminada en 0.

**Desventaja de usar `-print0` y `-0`**: No es portable. Esto funciona solo en GNU.

## Método 2: `-exec` (funciona en Unixes, fuera de GNU)

El comando find puede armar los comandos y ejecutarlos de esta forma:

```sh
find dirA -name "archivo*" -exec mv {} dirB \;
```

Donde `find` reemplaza `{}` por los archivos encontrados.

La desventaja de esto: `find` arma CADA COMANDO y lo ejecuta PARA CADA ARCHIVO. En casos donde find encuentra muchas ocurrencias, esto es un problema porque llama múltiples veces al comando externo y `xargs` se vuelve una mejor opción.

**Ventajas de `-exec`**: Este método es portable a otros Unixes, como BSD. Puede construir comandos donde el archivo encontrado con `find` aparece en cualquier parte.

**Desventaja**: Llama al comando una vez para cada archivo. Cuando la salida de `find` es extensa, esto es problemático.

## Referencias

[`man xargs`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-es-extra/xargs.1.es.html) (español)

[`man find`](http://es.tldp.org/Paginas-manual/man-pages-es-extra-0.8a/man1/find.1.html) (español)

Comment: Buena respuesta, se aprende mucho de ella.